# How to use nested classNames?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material-ui and I'm creating a progress bar.

I created these classes:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  progressSegment: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  item: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    marginRight: 2,
    height: 8,

    "&:first-child": {
      borderTopLeftRadius: 3,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 3,
    },

    "&:last-child": {
      borderTopRightRadius: 3,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 3,
    },

    "&.red-common": {
      background: "#D1132A",
    },

    "&.gold-common": {
      background: "#EBA75C",
    },

    "&.orange-common": {
      background: "#E4590F",
    },

    "&.yellow-common": {
      background: "#FFCD0F",
    },

    "&.yellow-light-common": {
      background: "#EACB16",
    },

    "&.green-light-common": {
      background: "#C1C625",
    },

    "&.green-common": {
      background: "#2CAC87",
    },
  },
});
```

Then in my component I created some `div` to render a progress bar. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: progress bar]

And this is my component:

```
export const SegmentedProgressBar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.progressSegment}>
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
      <div className={classes.item} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem is how can I pass these classes to my first nested div: `className="item red-common"` and so on for the next nested `div`?

I think I can use the `clsx` lib, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: to anybody looking for this solution, here is how I implemented this using a condition:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  progressSegment: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  item: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    marginRight: 2,
    height: 8,

    "&:first-child": {
      borderTopLeftRadius: 3,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 3,
    },

    "&:last-child": {
      borderTopRightRadius: 3,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 3,
    },

    "&.red-common": {
      background: "#D1132A",
    },

    "&.gold-common": {
      background: "#EBA75C",
    },

    "&.yellow-common": {
      background: "#FFCD0F",
    },

    "&.yellow-light-common": {
      background: "#EACB16",
    },

    "&.green-common": {
      background: "#2CAC87",
    },
  },
});

export const SegmentedProgressBar = ({ level = 0 }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.progressSegment}>
      <div className={`${classes.item} ${level >= 1 && "red-common"}`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} ${level >= 2 && "gold-common"}`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} ${level >= 3 && "yellow-common"}`} />
      <div
        className={`${classes.item} ${level >= 4 && "yellow-light-common"}`}
      />
      <div className={`${classes.item} ${level >= 5 && "green-common"}`} />
    </div>
  );
};

SegmentedProgressBar.propTypes = {
  level: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
export const SegmentedProgressBar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.progressSegment}>
      <div className={`${classes.item} red-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} gold-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} orange-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} yellow-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} yellow-light-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} green-light-common`} />
      <div className={`${classes.item} green-common`} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<div className={`${classes.item} ${classes.other-class}`}>
```

Or use clsx like you said.

https://nikitahl.com/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-in-react/

Or something like this too:

```
<div className={[class1, class2, class3].join(' ')} />
```